# How to update DateTime.Now binding purely within XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime

Suppose I have a `StatusBarItem` in my `StatusBar`, whose sole purpose is to display current `DateTime` information.  I know how to accomplish this from code-behind; however, I am trying to figure out a way to do it solely from XAML.

This is the XAML code I use:

```
<StatusBarItem Content="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt'}"/>
```

It displays the `DateTime` information of when I run the program, but I can't figure out a way to update it purely through XAML, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that only embedding inside XAML, Do something like this,

DateTime is not supported in resources when mapped [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/aa36e8eb-af23-41fb-8527-f99d43f3ad35/show-current-datetime-in-textblock-using-only-xaml).You can make use of timer by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ,

```
    namespace Sample.WpfExample
    {
    public class TickerC : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TickerC()
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second updates
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
        }

        public DateTime Now
        {
            get { return DateTime.Now; }
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

In XAML

```
   <Window.Resources>
   <src:TickerC x:Key="ticker" />
   </Window.Resources>

<StatusBarItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ticker}, Path=Now, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```